# How to fix reading the file in java

Tags: java, networking, udp

How to read sql data and store the data to a variable so can do a callculation!? Is there i spesific library in Java that can help me while working with sql data!?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: put the stackTrace of the error message you are getting when the code is crashed